# Why am I see different pages from Wikipedia?

Tags: java, html, http, web, wikipedia

When I open http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Births_by_year in any browser, I see category page with many subcategories and one subpage which is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_Sung-Baek

But when I read the same page with Java, I get category page with different content. Instead of subpage mentioned above it contains http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Mijotoba/Ruth_Stella_Correa_Palacio

How it can be? Why Wikipedia presents different page?

Setting `User-Agent` does not help.

**Headers requesting "normal" content**

```
GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Births_by_year HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: ru-RU,zh-CN;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: en.wikipedia.org
```

**Headers requesting "modified" content**

```
GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Births_by_year HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: en.wikipedia.org
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: I see "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Mijotoba/Ruth_Stella_Correa_Palacio" here, try reloading your browser cache with Ctrl+F5.

Comment: This is not browser cache since I see content in Fiddler2. Ctrl+F5 didn't help. I see first version in all browsers (IE, FF, GC)

Comment: Same here, OSX 10.8 + Chrome / Safari --> Ruth Stella Correa Palacio.

Comment: Chrome Dev here. What region of the world are you in? Are you sure it's accessing en.wikipedia.org?

Comment: Can you all guys please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_Sung-Baek page and see if it has "Births by year" category at the bottom?

Comment: Actually, this is almost definitely a cache issue. I'm seeing Park_Sung-Baek as the revision before the current one. What is the latest revision for you?

Comment: I am from Russia but I do all from the same computer with no remoting or virtualization. I sniff all content with Fiddler2 and see it differs.

Comment: @slugonamission from which to which?

Comment: It just changed from the User: link to the Park_Sung-Baek link...

Comment: @slugonamission I see that last revision is of August 25/2012 http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Births_by_year&oldid=509079769

Comment: I can only assume it was a spam edit that was deleted, since it has now changed properly for me.

Comment: @slugonamission so now you have the same in browser as me; how can it be? some javascript changes content which java can't execute?

Comment: I don't know. It's now showing the same for me, so I assume the page had changed/been edited soon, or the generation failed for whatever reason.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` line. Perhaps there's a gzipped cached version on the server?

Comment: @slugonamission I still have "spam" version in Java, i.e. it didn't change for java

Comment: In that case, I have no idea, it could be a cache somewhere.

Comment: @Jon this was it. When I send `gzip, deflate` for encoding, server sends encoded page Java can't undestand and it contains Park_Sung-Baek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks like a temporary issue with Wikipedia's front-end caches.  Specifically, when I request [the page in question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aBirths_by_year) from my browser (which sends the request header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`), the response I see contains the header:

```
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Sep 2012 16:46:55 GMT
```

If I request the same page using [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP.pm) from the command line (which does not send an `Accept-Encoding` header), the header looks very different:

```
Last-Modified: Sat, 25 Aug 2012 12:52:42 GMT
```

And, indeed, this latter response contains the same outdated content you report receiving with your Java client.

I suspect what happened is that, at some point in the past, a server glitch caused the outdated copy not to be purged from the cache when the page was changed.  In this particular instance, you can probably fix it by [purging the page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aPurge).  More generally, if you keep seeing such stale cached pages appearing in the future, you may want to report the issue to the [Wikipedia server admins](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Sysadmin), in case there's something wrong with the caches that needs fixing.

Ps. Why are you fetching the Wikipedia front-end HTML pages with Java anyway?  Generally, you should be using the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) instead.